# Convert epoch to human-readable date python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I want to convert from epoch to date
like that : `1575135888 ==> 3 years ago` (https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2ZPW.png)

I have this code :

```
date_c = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1575135888)
print(datetime.date.today())  
print(date_c)
```

I got `2022-12-09`

and `2019-11-30 18:44:48`

I don't know how to convert it to 3 years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could use timedelta like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.today() - datetime.fromtimestamp(1575135888), "ago")
```

Output:

```
1104 days, 15:57:21.760720 ago
```

But I'm afraid that the meaning of "years ago" is ambiguous:
Does it mean 365 days, 365.25 days?

Comment: thanks you i got what i need

my final code : 
`from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

date = str(pd.to_datetime(datetime.today()).date() - pd.to_datetime(datetime.fromtimestamp(1575135888)).date())
ok = slice(0,-9)
done=date[ok]
print(done)
`

to get only days

it doesn't matter if 365 days, 365.25 days
i just need close number

Comment: btw it's 1 year (365.24 days)